# onclick button shows an unwanted message position

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web page in

> http://enlaces.webcindario.com/paraprobar02.htm

that everything works fine. But when I press the CHECK ANSWER button shows the message at the top of the page. Also when you go to that page in a touchscreen device the message appears close to that same CHECK ANSWER button or to other CHECK ANSWER buttons.

I would like the message appears like in this other page of mine:

> http://enlaces.webcindario.com/addition.htm

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why use + scrollX? Isnt the popUp absolute? Either make popUp fixed with negative scrollX or just remove scrollX completely: absolute will already change position when you scroll.